# NullPointerException on setAdapter Android

Tags: java, android

I have NullpointeException on setAdapter, when Im trying to create massive of values
Activity main
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Toolbar toolbar;

private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.activiti_main;

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

private ViewPager viewPager;

String[] names = { "Иван", "Марья", "Петр", "Антон", "Даша", "Борис",
        "Костя", "Игорь", "Анна", "Денис", "Андрей" };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppDefault);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(LAYOUT);

    initToolbar();
    initNavigationView();
    initTabs();
    initList();


    }

private void initTabs() {
    viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    TabLayout  tabLayout=(TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    TabsFragmentAdapter adapter = new TabsFragmentAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void initToolbar(){
        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name); //наздвание
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() { //слушатель события для элементов которые выскакивают в меню
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu); //создаем менюшку и отсылаемся к файлу меню

    }

private void initNavigationView() {
    drawerLayout= (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.text_open,R.string.text_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.actionHistory: {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.actionIdea: {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.actionToDo: {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.actionBirthday: {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}


private void initList() {

    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

    lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

listlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello">
    </TextView>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and ideafragment

```
public class IdeaFragment extends AbstractTabFragment {

    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.listlayout;


    public static IdeaFragment getInstance(Context context){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        IdeaFragment fragment = new IdeaFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragment.setContext(context);
        fragment.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.tab_item_ideas));
        return fragment;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT,container,false);
        return view;
    }
    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


}
```

activiti_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/mainBackground">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
                />


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_plus"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXpzo.jpg)

However, the lv.setAdapter line right above this crashes the app with a null pointer exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: Null pointer exception hides here `    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names); check your code if there are enough arguments`

Comment: post activiti_main.xml

Comment: Maybe the line `ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);` results null for `lvMain`, so there is the exception on `setAdapter`, because the `findViewById` looks for `R.id.lvMain` in `R.layout.activiti_main`, but it is in `R.layout.listlayout`

Comment: @piotrek1543  I have enough arguments, i cant add more

Comment: and the layout is in a right activity, right? Check it patiently ;-)

Comment: The linked duplicate may not help as it only clarifies what a NPE in general is. You should wait for your Fragment's onViewCreated() call.

Comment: @piotrek1543  i dont understand,  what i need to check?

Comment: In your MainActivity the layout called R.layout.activiti_main, but the file you posted called activitymain.xml. Maybe here is the problem?

Comment: @alla i didnt post file i posted code, and write above wrong name,i'll fix it

Comment: @IlyaKulikov did you checked my comment above? If the `findViewById` method can't find the view in the layout (setted by `setContentView` method), it returns `null` so if you call `lvMain.setAdapter(...)`, it will throw a `NullPointerException`